# Index and length must refer to a location within the string

Tags: c#, string

I have some address  like this

**122/852 Mansrovar society,Jaipur, Rajastha,India**

where i need to write a function which extract  **Mansrovar society**  I tried below code but giving me error

```
 string BuildingAddress = txtAddress.Substring(0, txtAddress.IndexOf(','));
            BuildingAddress = BuildingAddress.Substring(BuildingAddress.IndexOf(' '), BuildingAddress.Length);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second argument of [`string.Substring(int, int)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs) is the *length* of the substring you want - so

```
BuildingAddress = BuildingAddress.Substring(BuildingAddress.IndexOf(' '),
                                            BuildingAddress.Length);
```

would only be valid if `IndexOf` returned 0.

If you just want "from the first space onwards" you can use the overload with a single parameter:

```
BuildingAddress = BuildingAddress.Substring(BuildingAddress.IndexOf(' '));
```

Note that that will still fail if the string doesn't contain a space - and it will have a leading space if it works. You might want:

```
BuildingAddress = BuildingAddress.Substring(BuildingAddress.IndexOf(' ') + 1);
```

which will *always* be valid, and skip the leading space - although it will only skip *one* space.

Answer (score 2):

`String.Substring` takes two arguments: `start` and `length`. You're using it as if the second one was `end`. It's not.

```
BuildingAddress =
    BuildingAddress.Substring(BuildingAddress.IndexOf(' '),
                              BuildingAddress.Length - BuildingAddress.IndexOf(' '));
```